# Minting ERC721 in Remix solidity unit testing

Tags: remix, nft, erc-721, unittesting, remix-tests

I am trying to unit test by minting from my NFT smart contract, which is utilizing `safeTransfer`, and the Remix VM is (rightly) denying my testing contract from minting an NFT because it hasn't implemented the appropriate IERC721Receiver method.

However, any attempt at implementing the appropriate IERC721Receiver yields errors in the Remix IDE.

Specifically, as I turn my contract into an `abstract` one and inherit `IERC721Receiver`
`abstract contract testSuite is IERC721Receiver`
I get the error: `contract deployment failed after trying twice: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.`

Increasing the gas limit in the `Deploy & run transactions` tab does not fix the issue.

Anyone have experience solving for this?

Much appreciated